# Can't get xls files from folder VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open xls format files from folder and get data from them using a macro workbook
but cannot do this. I am getting it as empty

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\New Folder"
qwe = Dir(sPath & "*.xls")
```

I am getting qwe as empty even though the folder is not empty it has 3 excel files of format xls.

Comment: You need to have a backslash at the end of `sPath`

Comment: I am using Excel 2007..it doesn't work...I get type mismatch qwe is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work, just add a slash to de in the new folder directory not all xls that start with 'New Folder' in the My Documents dir:

```
sPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\New Folder"
qwe = Dir(sPath & "\*.xls")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote and tested this in Excel 2010. It is very simple code and should work in Excel 2007.

This will enumerate all files that match *.xls

```
Public Sub GetFiles()

Dim spath As String
Dim file As String

spath = "<enter your path here with a trailing backslash>" 
'eg "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\New Folder\"

file = Dir(spath & "*.xls")

Do While file <> ""
    MsgBox (file)
    file = Dir
Loop


End Sub
```